# How to check a particular script execution is completed by a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I have a daemonset which deploys containers to check status of few mount points. This daemonset deployment is done from a python script and soon after the deployment command I am collecting the logs which will be created by above daemonset pods. I see that the logs are getting copied soon after the daemonset creation is triggered and for the same reason , logs are not complete.

After some investigation , I found that the daemonset pods are still in process of script execution and writing logs.Meanwhile the main script has already jumped to the next command of copying logs using `kubectl cp` command.

Is there any way I can put a wait based on the condition that copy logs only if script execution is completed.

This is the part of code I have

```
# Create diag pod
cmd = "kubectl apply -f diagnostic_daemon.yaml"
(rc, cmd_out, cmd_err) = cmdHandle.cmd_run(cmd)
if cmd_err.strip():
    print "ERROR: Unbale to create diag POD. Exiting!!!"
    print "> " + REDC + cmd_err.strip() + ENDC
    sys.exit(1)

# wait for the daemonset pod to reach running state
check_daemonset_state("cos-plugin-diag")

print "\n*****Collecting cos-plugin-diag logs*****"
# Collect diag pod logs
global nodeQdigl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you also need to check for the pods to be in `Running` state (all containers in the pod)

```
# wait for the pod 
check_pod_state("cos-plugin-diag")
```

So if the Pod has 2 containers, for example, you should check for `2/2`

Example:

```
NAME                                                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-node-9wnst                                                    2/2       Running   0          6d
```

The other aspect that you need to check a string in the log file that determines the end of your log and you can check it with

```
kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container-if-multiple-containers> -n <your-namespace>
```

Hope it helps